# do_shortcode() not working in admin plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have created an admin plugin where I wanted to make use of  shortcode in plugin file. I did as `do_shortcode('[code id=5]');` This is clearly working on post and other positions where it should. But, not working on the plugin. My code:

```
function applicant_new_form(){
   echo "<h3>Add new application</h3>";
   do_shortcode('[php snippet=3]');   
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: What exactly is the code, could you please write

Comment: why do you use echo inside of a function, you should use return inside of a function

Answer (score 1):

You didn't echo the code, please check. That should be:

```
function applicant_new_form(){
    echo "<h3>Add new application</h3>";
    echo do_shortcode('[php snippet=3]');
}
```

Comment: LOL, that was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Is the plugin some kind of widget? If so, try adding:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

to your functions.php file in the root of your theme.

Comment: No, plugin is not any kind of widget.

Comment: Have you tried echo'ing the do_shortcode? e.g <?php echo do_shortcode('yourShortcode'); ?>